# java regular expression [A-Z]{6}-[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{4}

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in Java for this:

```
"/[A-Z]{6}-[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{4}/"
```

But it is not working. For example

```
"AASAAA-AAAA-AAAA".matches("/[A-Z]{6}-[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{4}/")
```

returns `false`.

What is the correct way?

Comment: remove the forward slashes.

Comment: java uses a different REGEX engine. Not the same one used in JS or Perl. So, you don't need "/"s

Comment: @TheLostMind: java, JS and Perl have different regex engines, that is true. But the syntax with or without delimiters doesn't depend on the regex engine itself, but on the language syntax. For example, you can't find nowhere a reference to the use of delimiters in the PCRE documentation, but you will find it in the PHP manual only. The R language that can use PCRE too (with `PERL=true` mode) doesn't use delimiters at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Java` != `JavaScript`, here you don't need to surround regex with `/` so try with

```
"AASAAA-AAAA-AAAA".matches("[A-Z]{6}-[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{4}")
```

Otherwise your regex would search for substring which also has `/` at start and end.

BTW you need to know that `matches` checks if regex matches *entire* String, so

```
"aaa".matches("aa")
```

is same as

```
"aaa".matches("^aa$")
```

which would return `false` since String couldn't be fully matched by regex.

---

If you would like to find substrings which would match regex you would need to use

```
String input = "abcd";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\w{2}");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()){//this will try to find single match
     System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
ab
cd
```

Comment: what the $ and ^ mean? I want exacly "AASAAA-AAAA-AAAA" and not "AASAAA-AAAA-AAAAA" for example

Comment: @user1932595 `^` and `$` are *[anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)* which respectively represent start of the string and end of the string. For instance of you want to find `foo` which is placed at start of the string you can use regex `^foo`, similarly you can use `foo$` to look for `foo` which is right after end of the string. Combining them `^foo$` would mean you want to find/accept foo which is at start and at end of your string, which can happen only if string is only `foo`.

Comment: As mentioned earlier `matches` tests if regex can match entire string so `matches("regex")` is same as `matches("^regex$")`. If you want to match only `foo` but not `fooo` then `matches("foo")` will do what you need because it is essentially `matches("^foo$")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Z]{6}-[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{4}$
```

It's just you shouldn't put backslashes at the start and the end. Put instead ^ and $.
And ow I didn't see you have used the Javscript's syntax ! **Java != Javascript**

Comment: `matches` doesn't need `^` `$` flags because it checks if regex matches **entire** String by default.

Comment: It's possible too, but it's for a better regex. ^^